# How to set whisper.DecodingOptions language?

Tags: python, deep-learning, openai-whisper

I'm trying to run whisper and I want to set the `DecodingOptions`.language with France (instead of using it's language detection).

I have tried to write:

```
options = whisper.DecodingOptions()
options.language = "fr"
```

but I'm getting error:

```
FrozenInstanceError: cannot assign to field 'language'
```

How can I set the language in `DecodingOptions` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change the language in the `DecodingOptions` in Whisper with the following command (as, for example, shown [here](https://lablab.ai/t/whisper-tutorial)):

```
options = whisper.DecodingOptions(language="en")
```